# Float a bunch of divs CENTERED while retaining dynamic width and height

Tags: css, html, css-float, center

I've got a large div. It contains a bunch of thumbnails. I'd like the thumbnails within the div to be centered inside the div, and the div to be centered on the page. But I'd also like the width of the div to be dynamic so you can see all the thumbnails on every resolution, centered. How could I achieve this?

here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="thumb"><img /></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img /></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img /></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img /></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img /></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img /></div>
</div>
```

I've tried centering it with this css:
The problem is I need an alternative to float:left that works to center so they all float around each other. What I currently have just floats them left so on the wrong browser width, they're not centered.

```
#container{margin:auto;width:80%}
.thumb{padding:60px;float:left}
```

Any ideas on how to do something like float:center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot give the same ID to all the children `<div>`; That is invalid HTML.

I'd do something like this:

```
#container{margin:0 auto;width:80%;text-align:center}
#container div{padding:60px;display:inline}

<div id="container">
    <div><img /></div>
    <div><img /></div>
    <div><img /></div>
    <div><img /></div>
    <div><img /></div>
    <div><img /></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could just change all the `<div>`s to `<span>`s and remove the `display:inline` CSS directive. You could also completely remove the `<div>` or `<span>` idea and just apply the `padding` directly to the `img` tag.

**EDIT**: Seeing comments posted on another answer, it looks like my answer above still won't exactly help you. Is this the behavior you're trying to accomplish? http://jsfiddle.net/9KqQN/1

```
#container{margin:0 auto;width:80%;text-align:center}
#container span{display:inline-block;text-align:left}

<div id="container">
    <span>
        <img />
        <img />
        <img />
        <br />
        <img />
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops, I wrote class in my code, accidentally wrote ID here. Sorry.

Comment: See edit in my answer for possible solution based on your comments on @Marc B's answer.

Comment: But I'd like the next line to start on the left. Left alignment of the thumbs, but a dynamic with of the container, centered. Is it even possible? I don't want a centered look to the thumbs, I'd like the thumbs to be left aligned.

Comment: The behavior is exactly what's happening in that fiddle I linked. Play with it, add some more `img` tags and some more breaks. The green bordered `<span>` will grow in width if you add more on the same line. It will also start images on the left if you break to a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` on the thumb divs. This lets you treat them like any other piece of text, but retains their inherent "boxiness" for sizing:

```
#container {margin: auto; width: 80%; text-align: center; }
.thumb { height: 100px; width: 100px; padding: 60px; display-inline-block; }
```

Comment: Might want to edit the comment and clean it up a bit. Don't want the FCC going all janet jackson on you.

Comment: Oh no, never mind. That centers the images too, I just want them to float to the center as a whole, now they're actually centered so the second line starts in the middle, I want it to start on the left! Like left aligned text.

Comment: Hmm. Wrap the images in another div ("subcontainer"), and make that be text-align: left. That should make #container center the #subcontainer, which then left-aligns the .thumb boxes.

Comment: Then I'm right back where I started. It left aligns everything. I don't think it's possible.